# SharePoint Resource Data

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010 is there any list specific to storing resource string?

What are the other alternatives available to store resource strings in SharePoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the free [SharePoint development Guidelines](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/05/muhimbis-sharepoint-development.html). It has a section on dealing with resources / localisation.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint doesn't have anything internal for managing Resources.

SharePoint does, however, allow you to use regular Resource (resx) files.

Comment: Thanks Justin... Could you provide me some reference on using Resource files. I have used it with ASP.NET. Is it any different here?

Comment: Also, whats the preferred way? Using Sharepoint Lists or resx?